# Dynamically picking up the file name in bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am running a bat file in different users laptops

Some users having this path `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\1.8.0`

some users having this path `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\1.9.0`

In my bacth file --I used only the path `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\1.8.0`

for users which are having 1.9.0 this code is not working.

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your script is using user profiles folder structure :

```
 C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local
```

This can be acheived using `%localappdata%` instead :

so in your script you can do as below :

```
CD %localappdata%
if exist Google\1.8.0 CD Google\1.8.0
if exist Google\1.8.0 CD Google\1.9.0
```

And then rest of your script will be same

Above code would first CD to Local folder and then search for required folder structure rest you can play with i beileve

Comment: Why not use `%localappdata%` instead? that will directly go to the local folder. Also, with your code you still need to use `cd Local` before you check the google folder

Comment: @Dennis van Gils Thanks , modified my code with your suggestion , i believe cd Local is not required , %temp% would change your directory one step ahead of Local folder , so by cd .. you would be in Local folder.

Answer (score -1):

Use a Find-n-Replace-across-files feature from a tool such as Notepad++ and change the path to whichever is the correct path for the laptop you are running from. Or if you want a batch file for that, the Find Replace tool https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/ can help. If you are doing this often, then you might want to consider AutoIT to develop your own additional script. Or, then, Python.

Comment: Your solution is effectively to tell the users to edit the script themselves. That is hardly a solution.

Comment: Disagree. I am not asking users (of laptops) to change the script, I am suggesting how the Admin (the one who runs the scripts) can do it as a batch, in a click-to-run fashion with a replacer batch file.

Comment: You're telling him to change the script on a case-by-case basis. That gets incredibly tedious really fast.